# How to test in Safari on Windows?

Tags: css, windows, browser, safari, web-frontend

I'm frontend developer, When I design a web page with css in Safari browser, it renders differently from other browsers like Chrome, Firefox.
How do I use Safari browser on windows to test my web pages.

Comment: Safari for Windows has been discontinued by Apple long time ago.

Comment: I guess, to use Safari on Windows, you can use some tools like https://www.browserstack.com/

Answer (score 1):

Now its not possible to install it. Alternative is that you can try to do it on linux ubuntu (or virtualbox on windows and there ubuntu and safari).

There are two potential workarounds for installing Safari on Linux: using WINE (the compatibility layer, not the drink) or using WINE and PlayOnLinux, which provides a graphical user interface (UI) for WINE.

https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-safari-on-linux/

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to download the MacOs and install in a virtual machine like VmWare or Virtualbox. You can also use real-time safari browser using these [website](https://www.lambdatest.com/test-on-safari-browsers). There are many free real-time safari browser too.